# How can I tombstone the child VMs in caliburn.micro

Tags: windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro, tombstoning

I run into some problems with tombstoning in Caliburn.Micro. I have a pivot control in which we have a listbox in every pivot control item. I just to want to save the list(s) using caliburn.micro's built-in support

I Have a MainViewModel which will initialize a series child VMs in a pilot control

```
public class MainViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    private readonly Func<QiushiListViewModel> _createQiushiListViewModel;
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _events;
    readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;
    readonly Func<AboutUsViewModel> _aboutUsViewModelFactory;
    readonly Func<SettingsViewModel> _settingsViewModelFactory;

    public MainViewModel(Func<QiushiListViewModel> createQiushiListViewModel, 
                        INavigationService navigationService,
                        IEventAggregator events,
                        IWindowManager windowManager, 
                        Func<AboutUsViewModel> aboutUsViewModelFactory,
                        Func<SettingsViewModel> settingsViewModelFactory
                        )
    {
        _createQiushiListViewModel = createQiushiListViewModel;
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _events = events;
        _windowManager = windowManager;
        _aboutUsViewModelFactory = aboutUsViewModelFactory;
        _settingsViewModelFactory = settingsViewModelFactory;
    }

    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        if(Items.Count==0)
        {
            Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Apply(x =>
            {
                var pivot = _createQiushiListViewModel();
                switch (x)
                {
                    case 1:
                        pivot.DisplayName = AppResources.App_Pivot_First;
                        pivot.Section = "late";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pivot.DisplayName = AppResources.App_Pivot_Second;
                        pivot.Section = "pic";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pivot.DisplayName = AppResources.App_Pivot_Third;
                        pivot.Section = "8hr";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pivot.DisplayName = AppResources.App_Pivot_Fourth;
                        pivot.Section = "week";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        pivot.DisplayName = AppResources.App_Pivot_Fifth;
                        pivot.Section = "month";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                Items.Add(pivot);
            });
            ActivateItem(Items[0]);    
        }
        ...
    }

}
```

And the child VM is as follows

```
public class QiushiListViewModel : 
        Screen, 
        IHandle<RefreshListMessage>, 
        IHandle<RetrieveNewItemsMessage>, 
        IHandle<TaskCompleted<EmailComposeTask>>, 
        IHandle<TaskCompleted<SmsComposeTask>>
    {
        private const int DefaultItemsPerPage = 20;
        readonly IEventAggregator _events;
        private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

        public QiushiListViewModel(
            IEventAggregator events,
            INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            ItemsPerPage = DefaultItemsPerPage;
            _events = events;
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _qiushiItems = new SortableObservableCollection<QiushiItem>();
        }

        protected override void OnActivate()
        {
            _events.Subscribe(this);
            base.OnActivate();

        }

        protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
        {
            SelectedItem = null;
            _events.Unsubscribe(this);
            base.OnDeactivate(close);
        }

        public string Section { get; set; }

        public int Page { get; set; }

        public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }

        public int CountOfItemsUpdated { get; set; }

        public bool HasErrors { get; set; }

        private SortableObservableCollection<QiushiItem> _qiushiItems;

        public IEnumerable<QiushiItem> QiushiItems
        {
            get { return _qiushiItems; }
        }

        private bool _isBusy;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return _isBusy; }
            set
            {
                if (_isBusy == value)
                    return;
                _isBusy = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsBusy);
            }
        }

        private bool _canLoadMore;
        public bool CanLoadMore
        {
            get { return _canLoadMore; }
            set
            {
                if (_canLoadMore == value)
                    return;
                _canLoadMore = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanLoadMore);
            }
        }

        private QiushiItem _selectedItem;
        public QiushiItem SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if(_selectedItem == value)
                    return;
                _selectedItem = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedItem);
            }
        }

    ...
    }
```

I tried to implement the QiushiListViewModelStorage

```
public override void Configure()
        {
            Id(x=>x.Section);

            Property(x => x.CanLoadMore).InAppSettings();
            Property(x => x.IsBusy).InAppSettings();
            Property(x => x.Page).InAppSettings();
            Property(x => x.QiushiItems).InAppSettings();
        }
```

It does not work, nothing happened, no errors, no exceptions. QiushiItem class is serializable, please see the following snippet

```
[DataContract]
    public class QiushiItem : IComparable, IEqualityComparer<QiushiItem>
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MobileImageUrl { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Tags { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Tops { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Flops { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int CommentsCount { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime PublishDateTime { get; set; }

        public string Age
        {
            get
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(PublishDateTime).Minutes < 10)
                    return AppResources.App_TimeSpan_JustNow;
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(PublishDateTime).Minutes < 30)
                    return AppResources.App_TimeSpan_Recently;
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(PublishDateTime).Minutes < 60)
                    return AppResources.App_TimeSpan_Half_Hour_Ago;
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(PublishDateTime).Hours < 2)
                    return AppResources.App_TimeSpan_An_Hour_Ago;
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(PublishDateTime).Hours < 3)
                    return AppResources.App_TimeSpan_Two_Hours_Ago;
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(PublishDateTime).Hours < 24)
                    return AppResources.App_TimeSpan_In_One_Day;
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(PublishDateTime).Days < 2)
                    return AppResources.App_TimeSpan_One_Day_Ago;
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(PublishDateTime).Days < 3)
                    return AppResources.App_TimeSpan_Two_Days_Ago;
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(PublishDateTime).Days < 7)
                    return AppResources.App_TimeSpan_In_A_Week;
                return DateTime.Now.Subtract(PublishDateTime).Days < 30 ? AppResources.App_TimeSpan_In_A_Month : AppResources.App_TimeSpan_Long_Ago;
            }
        }

        int IComparable.CompareTo(object right)
        {
            if (!(right is QiushiItem)) throw new ArgumentException(AppResources.Ex_QiushiItem_Comparable_Argument_Exception, "right");
            QiushiItem righItem = (QiushiItem) right;
            return CompareTo(righItem);
        }

        public int CompareTo(QiushiItem right)
        {
            return Id.CompareTo(right.Id);
        }

        // Relational Operators.
        public static bool operator <(QiushiItem left, QiushiItem right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) < 0;
        }
        public static bool operator <=(QiushiItem left, QiushiItem right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) <= 0;
        }
        public static bool operator >(QiushiItem left, QiushiItem right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) > 0;
        }
        public static bool operator >=(QiushiItem left, QiushiItem right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) >= 0;
        }

        private static DateTimeComparer _datetimeComparer;
        public static IComparer DateTimeCompare
        {
            get
            {
                if (_datetimeComparer == null)
                    _datetimeComparer = new DateTimeComparer();
                return _datetimeComparer;
            }
        }

        private class DateTimeComparer : IComparer
        {
            #region IComparer Members
            int IComparer.Compare(object left, object right)
            {
                if (!(left is QiushiItem))
                    throw new ArgumentException(AppResources.Ex_QiushiItem_Comparable_Argument_Exception, "left");
                if (!(right is QiushiItem))
                    throw new ArgumentException(AppResources.Ex_QiushiItem_Comparable_Argument_Exception, "right");
                QiushiItem leftItem = (QiushiItem)left;
                QiushiItem rightItem = (QiushiItem)right;
                return leftItem.PublishDateTime.CompareTo(
                 rightItem.PublishDateTime);
            }
            #endregion

        }

        public bool Equals(QiushiItem x, QiushiItem y)
        {
            if (x.Id == y.Id)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(QiushiItem obj)
        {
            return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Besides above, I also tried using custom serialization

```
public override void Configure()
        {
            Id(x=>x.Section);
            Property(x => x.QiushiItems).InAppSettings();
            Property(x => x.QiushiItems).InAppSettings().Configure(x =>
                                                                       {
                                                                           x.Save = SaveStrokes;
                                                                           x.Restore = RestoreStrokes;
                                                                       });
        }

        void SaveStrokes(QiushiListViewModel vm, Func<string> serialize, StorageMode nMode)
        {
            IsolatedStorageHelper.SaveObject(vm.Section, vm.QiushiItems);
        }

        void RestoreStrokes(QiushiListViewModel vm, Func<string> serialize, StorageMode nMode)
        {
            // use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[vm.DisplayName + "ThePropertyKey"] 
            // to check if the key exists, and if it is there get the serialized data and deserialize
            if (vm.Section == null)
                return;
            if(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[vm.Section]!=null) 
                IsolatedStorageHelper.GetObject<IEnumerable<QiushiItem>>(vm.Section);
        }
```

However, the problem is there are 5 QiushiListViewModels, when tombstoning, the save/restore will be called 5 times, I cannot tell which is which.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance -Peng

Answer (score 0):

I'm no WP7 expert, but have you tried decorating the classes and properties with the `[SurviveTombstone]` attribute?

> The `[SurviveTombstone]` attribute is a simple out-of-the-box
>   implementation of [the ITombstone] interface that understands how to walk an
>   object graph, examine its properties and persist them.

More details here under the '**Tombstoning**' header:
http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/08/07/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-pt-4-working-with-windows-phone-7.aspx